# How to use WSDL2Code generated files?

Tags: android, asmx, ksoap2, android-ksoap2, android-parser

I am working towards an android application. I need to use a web service. I have a .NET web service. I generated Java files from [WSDL2Code](http://www.wsdl2code.com/Pages/Home.aspx) converter, but I don't know how can I use service with these files, because there are no examples. I'm implementing client side.  If Anyone know how to solve this please help me..

Comment: will you need to know how to consume the webservice in android?

Comment: yes.. i follow this tutorial..
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304302/Calling-Asp-Net-Webservice-ASMX-From-an-Android-Ap
they r use a sample web service ans it worked fine. But when i use my web service it s not worked. after googling i found WSDL2Code.com site they are giving a java files to consume webservice. but i dont know how to use that files.

Comment: @bCliks did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

in this site there is an example section, and u cant contact support@wsdl2code.com for help...

in general the class - "servicename" has all the methods
for example (copy paste from the site)

```
 SampleService srv1 = new SampleService();
 req = new Request();                     
 req.companyId = "1";
 req.userName = "userName";                                     
 req.password = "pas";
 Response response =    srv1.ServiceSample(req);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check on the generated file, "SampleService.java" the attribute "url", maybe is empty. Fill with your web service URL.

```
public String NAMESPACE ="http://************/";
public String url="";
public int timeOut = 60000;
public IWsdl2CodeEvents eventHandler;
public SoapProtocolVersion soapVersion;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the service class (eg : Log_Service), you can see that the url property is empty.
before consuming the methods, you can set it in the instance.

```
 ls = new Log_Service();
 ls.setUrl('http://ws.whatyouwant.here');
```

and then make your request.